# Why isn't $x_2+x_3+x_4\le 2$ a cutting plane?

Tags: branch-and-cut, cutting-planes

[image]

In my textbook, to generate cutting planes, they tell you to proceed as follows:

A procedure for generating cutting planes:

> 1. Select a ($\le$) constraint that has only nonnegative coefficients.
> 2. Find a group of variables such that
>
> a) The constraint is violated when all variables in the group equals 1
>   and the remaining variables equal to 0.
>
> b) But the constraint is satisfied if any one of the variables in the
>   group is changed from 1 to 0.
>
> 3. Suppose there are $K$ variables in the group add the following
>      constraint as a new cutting plane:
>      Sum of variables in the group $\le  − 1$

**My Question:** Why isn't $x_2+x_3+x_4\le 2$ a cutting plane? Since if we go by 2a) , and put $x_2=1 , x_3=1 , x_4=1$ and $x_1=0$ , then it violates the inequality? Since $11>7$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a cutting plane, but it is implied by $x_2+x_4\le 1$ and $x_3\le 1$ so not very useful.

Comment: Oh okay, i see. Thanks!